# How to Check a String is in datetime format or not in java

Tags: java

Is their a method in java to check weather a given string is Date or not. 
**example:**

```
 String s="Hello"              //is not Date <br>
 String s="01/05/2014"         //is a valid date
```

thank You.

Comment: Try to parse it with a `SimpleDateFormat` and see if that works.

Comment: Florent Bayle's solution is perfect if the format is known pre-parsing. If OP is looking for a universal dateValidator much like PHP's (utterly broken) `strtotime` then I'm afraid he's out of luck.

Comment: I would test it with a regular expression. For example `[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}`.

Comment: I think a two-step solution is in many situations preferable: First, use the regex (@ChristopheDeTroyer) to check if the string looks like a date; if it matches, use SimpleDateFormat.parse to verfiy that it is a valid date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for a specific format using SimpleDateFormat ex:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");

try
{
   df.parse("01/05/2014");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  //not a date
}
```

Comment: I would rather catch for ParseException.

Comment: @Journeycorner that is fine too you can catch whatever exception you want

Comment: @brs05: It would hide (runtime)exceptions. Imagine the input is null, doing it your way the NullPointerException would also be caught - not the finest way imho.

Answer (score 2):

Write simple API that will validate string is date or not,

If `isValidDate(String date)` return `true` then your string is date otherwise it is not date.

```
public boolean isValidDate(String date){
   SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
   boolean flag = true;

   try{
      dateFormat.parse(date); 
   }catch(ParseException e){
      flag = false;
   }
 return flag;
}
```

Comment: Don't catch `Exception`, try `ParseException` instead.